# How to exclude an C enum case when using the type in Swift

Tags: c, swift, enums

In my C code I generally have an enum case called count at the end. But when I use my enum in Swift it will also have that value, which I must handle in switch statements.

Is there some attribute I can use to exclude a case when importing into Swift?

Comment: Even in C, you have to handle the `count` case if `count` is part of the enum (e.g.) `enum myenum { opt_0, opt_1, opt_2, opt_3, count_of_options };` With `void foo(enum myenum val) { switch (val) { case ...: break; ... case count_of_options: break; }` You can use `default:` but, then, if you _miss_ a `case` for a valid option, it won't be flagged at compile time. Try compiling your C code with `-Wall`. You may get: _warning: enumeration value ‘count’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]_

Comment: @CraigEstey Would you recommend that I just handle the case in swift? I've been grouping it with `.unknown`/etc when that's also an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know swift. I responded because I noticed that you probably had the same quandary in C. I've sometimes left `count` _outside_ the `enum` and then did: `#define count_of_options (opt_3 + 1)` [a bit of a hack]. If you do: `switch ((int) val)` it does _no_ checking. Sometimes, I've wrapped the stuff in a CPP macro that goes back and forth. The problem is sometimes you _don't_ want to handle all cases in a given switch, and I've used `default: break;` there. With macro trickery: DEFAULT_BREAK where this compiles in two modes. But, I'd say the simplest is to include the count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` macro on enumerators:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(unsigned, Foo) {
    bar,
    baz,
    count NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Count does not represent a case")
};
```

`NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`, like any `__attribute__` that you want to apply to an enumerator, goes after the enumerator name but before the `=` if you need one.

The macro is defined if you include `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`. If you include CoreFoundation, you get `CF_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`, which does the same thing. If you include neither, you can use the long form:

```
__attribute__((availability(swift, unavailable, message="your message")))
```

Enumerators that are annotated with `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` won't show up in autocomplete, and won't cause build issues if they're not handled on the Swift side. If you attempt to use it, you get a hard error that includes your message.

Keep in mind that starting with Swift 5, you may need to use [`NS_CLOSED_ENUM`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_release_notes/ios_12_release_notes/foundation_release_notes?language=objc#3035774) instead of `NS_ENUM` if your purpose is to avoid having a `default` case.

Comment: How does the argument to this macro show up (e.g. info/warning message)? Or, is just annotation for the programmer that is ignored?

Comment: @CraigEstey, `count` does not appear in autocomplete, and if you use it anyway, you get a hard error: *'count' is unavailable in Swift: Count does not represent a case*.

Comment: I definitely tried this but I was using `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` and was importing CoreFoundation! It didn't compile and I didn't understand why. Thank you! The error I was getting was `Expected '= constant-expression' or end of enumerator definition`.

Comment: We have an interesting scenario at work. On our own computers, Swift code with Obj-C initializers like CGRectMake compiles just fine, but produces an error on the build server saying it has been explicitly marked unavailable. If I command-click on the function, it goes into the Obj-C header, and I see nothing of the sort. Is there something we can do to make our local behave like the build server? I can't add this macro, because the file is read-only.